# Getting error "missing grant type" while generating token

Tags: python, django

When im trying to generate token then im getting missing grant type error . Even if I'm passing grant type in payload

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def merchanttokengeneration(request):

    payload = request.data


    token = request.META.get('HTTP_TOKEN')

    headers = {"token": token, "Content-Type":"application/json"}
    print(headers)

    response = requests.request("POST",'https://staging/merchant/v1/oauth/token', data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(payload.get('username'), payload.get('password') ))

    print(response)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: please show traceback

Comment: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"}

Comment: It clearly cannot see the grant type so show what is being passed

Comment: In payload ,grant type is passed.   payload = {'username':'apnacomplex', 'password':'welcome@123', 'grant_type':'password'}

Comment: Can you try specifying the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in headers?

Comment: I have tried it already but still getting same error

Comment: Did you try with postman? Are you getting the same error? A similar kind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962573/missing-grant-type-error?rq=1

Comment: I have seen this already and im trying with postman only . But still it doesn't get solved

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: you sure you have created grant_type password in your backend ??